# Playing audio using kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer

Tags: core-audio, audiounit, audio-player, extaudiofileread

I successfully implemented an audio file player using the remote I/O audio unit and a render callback where I use ExtAudioFileRead to render audio frames.

At this moment I was just wondering what the difference would be of using kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer instead of a render callback with ExtAudioFileRead. What would be the advantage of this approach?

From the apple documentation I cannot deduct the differences.

Comment: Depends on your implementation of extaudiofile/audio units.  If you're doing reads on the render thread, I would switch to the audio file player.  If you've done it properly, reading from file on a separated thread in to a buffer that gets consumed on the render thread.  Then I might stay with audio units, mostly because you have more control.  Maybe test cpu usage.  I'd assume Apple would have optimized their player.